# How to count the number of unique customer_ids that overlap in combined categories per month in a Python DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I am working with a Python DataFrame that contains financial transaction information. The DataFrame has the following relevant columns: customer_id, date, product_type. Each row represents a transaction made by a customer in a specific month, and product_type indicates the transaction category.

My goal is to count the number of unique customer_id values that overlap in combined categories for each month. In other words, I want to know how many customers have transactions in more than one category in a specific month.

For example, if there are 10 unique customer_id values in the "Category A" and 6 unique customer_id values in "Category B" in June 2022, how can I count how many of these customer_id values overlap in both categories in that month?

the input table is like this:

| customer_id | branch_id | product_type | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CustomerId1 | Branch1 | Category A | 2022-06-30 22:47:35 |
| CustomerId2 | Branch2 | Category B | 2022-06-30 22:43:21 |
| CustomerId3 | Branch3 | Category A | 2022-06-30 22:43:04 |
| CustomerId4 | Branch1 | Category C | 2022-06-30 22:42:42 |
| CustomerId5 | Branch2 | Category B | 2022-06-30 22:31:03 |
| CustomerId6 | Branch3 | Category A | 2022-06-30 22:47:35 |
| CustomerId7 | Branch1 | Category D | 2022-06-30 22:43:21 |
| CustomerId8 | Branch2 | Category C | 2022-06-30 22:43:04 |
| CustomerId9 | Branch3 | Category E | 2022-06-30 22:42:42 |
| CustomerId10 | Branch1 | Category B | 2022-06-30 22:31:03 |

Here is part of the code I have tried to address this problem:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

# DataFrame df with transaction information

categories = ["Category A", "Category B", "Category C", "Category D", "Category E"]

combined_tables = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(1, len(categories) + 1):
    for combo in combinations(categories, i):
        combo_name = ' & '.join(combo)
        filtered_df = df[df['product_type'].isin(combo)]
        
        # Count how many customer_ids overlap in the same category in each month
        grouped = filtered_df.groupby(['year', 'month', 'product_type'])['customer_id'].nunique().reset_index()
        grouped.rename(columns={'customer_id': combo_name}, inplace=True)
        
        if combined_tables.empty:
            combined_tables = grouped
        else:
            combined_tables = combined_tables.merge(grouped, on=['year', 'month', 'product_type'], how='left')
```

I hope to obtain a DataFrame that shows the count of unique customer_id values that overlap in the combined categories for each month. The result should have columns for the year, month, category combinations, and the values should represent the count of unique customer_id values.

I expect a tabla like this one:

| year | month | Category A | Category B | Category C | Category A & Category B | Category A & Category C | Category B & Category C | Category A & Category B & Category C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 6 | 10 | 6 | 8 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 2022 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022 | 8 | 6 | 5 | 7 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 2022 | 9 | 9 | 4 | 8 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 2022 | 10 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022 | 11 | 7 | 8 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022 | 12 | 8 | 9 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023 | 1 | 9 | 6 | 7 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023 | 2 | 7 | 5 | 8 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 2023 | 3 | 8 | 4 | 9 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 2023 | 4 | 6 | 7 | 6 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023 | 5 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 2023 | 6 | 6 | 5 | 8 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 2023 | 7 | 7 | 4 | 9 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

with all possible combinations between categories

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there small input dataframe and expected output? With correct formatting.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a ton of information about the input dataframe, but I tried to put together an idea for you using nested dictionaries alongside the `len()` and `set()` functions. See below.

```
data={}
for category in set(df.product_type):
    data[category]={}
    for y in set(df.year):
        data[category][y]={}
        for m in set(df.month):
            data[category][y][m]=[]
for row in range(len(df)):
    category=df.iat[row,list(df.columns).index('product_type')]
    y=df.iat[row,list(df.columns).index('year')]
    m=df.iat[row,list(df.columns).index('month')]
    cid=df.iat[row,list(df.columns).index('customer_id')]
    data[category][y][m]+=[cid]

header=['year','month']+list(set(df.product_type))
rows=[]
for y in set(df.year):
    for m in set(df.month):
        l=[y,m]
        for c in header[2:]:
            l+=[len(set(data[c][y][m]))]
        rows+=[l]
pd.DataFrame(data=rows,columns=header)
```

It could definitely be improved on and optimized but it works very well. I ran it on a sample input with 100,000 rows and it took around 8 seconds for my computer. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, I updated the question to include an example input table